# Notepad++ does not have debugging capability or any debugging plug-in - is this true?

Tags: php, debugging, notepad++

For those who code in Notepad++, I just want to confirm that Notepad++ does not have any built-in debugging function (i.e. ability to set breakpoints, step one by one and look at values in the middle of execution).  I'm new to PHP coding and am looking for a good editor/IDE to use.  Since I would like a debugging function, your answer would greatly help me narrow my choices.  Note that I've recently downloaded and am in fact using Notepad++ at the moment, and cannot seem to find either a built-in debugger or a debugging plug-in from the Notepad++ menus.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like a question for http://Superuser.com

Comment: @Peter Ajtai debugging code is a user question?  Really?

Comment: @The Rook - I meant in terms of discussing Notepad++ functionality ==> http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/notepad%2b%2b .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is the [DBGP Plugin for NP++](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/DBGP%20Plugin/) that hooks into xDebug if you want to try it.

I found decent install/setup instructions [here](http://www.webcheatsheet.com/php/debug_php_with_xdebug.php), but as with most things computer related, YMMV.

Comment: Just figured I'd contribute. I haven't even used PHP in years, personally, but you never know what people are going to like. I use software that was originally written on KDE2/3 because I still like it as much now as I did six years ago.

Comment: Could anyone else who is using Notepad++ confirm that there's no built-in debugger in Notepad++?  If there is, please tell me how to access it.  Thanks.

Comment: Sure. I make a living writing PHP on Notepad++. The debugger is available as a plugin, as NPP is not a PHP-only editor and it makes no sense to force it upon those writing C, Java or whatever.

Beta or not, I've been using it for some years now and I'm totally fine with it.

Comment: To all who answered: Thanks, I truly appreciate your comments.  I ended up trying NetBeans IDE 6.9.1 and the XDebug works fine on that, which was a relief because I've read some terrible experiences posted.  I was mainly looking for a relatively light-weight, stable PHP editor or IDE that has a good, working debugger, and so far NetBeans fits that bill (although I've only used it for a short time).

Comment: I've been also debugging for quite some time using the Npp + xdebug + dgbp combo and it works beautifully. I'm personally happy with this setting.

Answer (score 1):

I like the new Eclipse Helios with PDT 2.2 which hooks into xDebug.  If you haven't used eclipse in a while you should check out the new version.  The new build of PDT is by far the best PHP debugger I have used.

Comment: Thanks.  I also prefer a light-weight PHP editor/IDE, so that was why I'm trying Notepad++.  Have heard that Eclipse PDT is somewhat slow and bloated.  Is this your experience?  Since you say it's the best PHP debugger you've used, I'm taking note and might try it.

Comment: @creativekev I totally agree and I often use scite which is the raw editor that powers notepad++ (works well under linux).  The new eclipse is faster,  the startup time is kind of slow but after its loaded its plenty fast and its the best way I have found to debug PHP. You can even debug code on a remote server.

Comment: @The Rook - Glad to hear your experience w Eclipse that it's fast enough.  I've also read comments saying Eclipse PDT crashes people's systems.  This probably gives me the most pause in terms of trying it.  Again, what's your experience - any crashes?  If so, how frequent and how bad?

Comment: @creativekev older versions where pretty bad, and crashing wasn't the only problem.  The newest build is fantastic I haven't had to file a single bug report.

Comment: @The Rook - Thanks.  I'm still evaluating my choices, but I'm definitely keeping Eclipse PDT in mind as a PHP IDE to try.  While I do prefer faster, more light-weight editors/IDEs, I'm open to using a more full-featured IDE as long as it does not crash my system and is reasonably fast, and of course, has a debugger.

Comment: @creativekev if you find a better one you should post an answer here.  "Zend IDE" is another choice and has awesome built-in docs and error detection, but its built from eclipse.  NetBeans also has a PHP debugger,  but its terrabad.

Comment: @The Rook - Yes I've read comments about Netbeans for PHP.  It seems people rave about it overall, but have major complaints about its Xdebug integration, with quite a few comments on this site alone saying they could not get the Xdebug in Netbeans to work - that stops me cold.  I don't really have a lot of time (or experience) to tinker with configs and such - looking for tools that work out of the box.  Sounds like Eclipse PDT fits the bill.  Also, have read that Zend both crashes systems and is slow nowadays.

Answer (score -1):

Try Eclipse w/Zend PDT.  The Zend debugger is much stronger than xDebug and it also introspects your code so you can ctrl-click a function call and it will take you to the declaration.

Comment: Why do you think is the Zend Debugger much stronger than xDebug?