# Any suggestions for the c++ debugger for notepad++?

Tags: c++, notepad++

I am quite new to notepad++.
Just now I am using gdb to debug c++. But gdb can only be operated through command line.
Is there a better debugger for c++ that I can operate in notepad++, such as setting breakpoints or something...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you need an IDE, use an IDE. Thats simple.

Comment: What about using an IDE instead of text editor and commandline debugging (e.g. Eclipse CDT)?

Comment: Why are you using Notepad++ ? a lot of free IDE offer multi language support and powerful editions capabilities... Eclipse, SublimeText ....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Notepad++ does not have debugging capability or any debugging plug-in - is this true?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427618/notepad-does-not-have-debugging-capability-or-any-debugging-plug-in-is-this)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there isn't a debugger for c++ on notepad++.

You might wanna check out some IDE's like Eclipse with CDT, or you can try Microsoft's Visual Studio if you are using Windows.